# Equivalent of EE admin info code

Tags: admin, craft-pro

Just wondering: Is there a equivalent for this piece of code written in EE:

```
{if logged_in}
    <div id=“admin”>
        Page render time: {elapsed_time} sec | 
        Queries: {total_queries} | 
        Gzip: {gzip_mode}  | 
        EE version: {app_version} build {app_build}
    </div>
{/if}
```

Source: http://www.blue-dreamer.co.uk/blog/entry/expressionengine-measuring-performance-during-development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly. But if you're looking for stats, [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode) does some query profiling right in the console:

[image: Query Profiling]

I'm not sure if you're looking for a 1-1 correlation but you can obtain whether or not the server supports gzip with the Server variable `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` (kind of useless IMO). Craft also will display its version number at the bottom of the CP when you're logged in, so I don't really see value there either but you can get it via your templates (see below).

If you need more than that, you could always make a simple plugin (I like to start with [Lindsey D's Business Logic](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic)  boilerplate variable class) and then just grab the data you need.

To only display the data to admins when they're logged in, you can do so like:

```
{% if currentUser and currentUser.admin %}
  Craft {{ craft.app.getEditionName()}} {{ craft.app.getVersion() }}.{{ craft.app.getBuild() }}
    ... do other stuff
{% endif %}
```